# waiting for ajax calls to end with Watir 6

Tags: jquery, ajax, watir, browser-automation

I used to be able to do it like this with watir-webdriver:

```
Watir::Wait.until(30) {browser.execute_script("return jQuery.active") == 0}
```

Now until method in Wait is deprecated and I get a bunch of warnings. 
When I look through Watir 6 documentation Wait can only be called on an element

How do I re-write `Watir::Wait.until(30) {browser.execute_script("return jQuery.active") == 0}` for Watir 6 not to get warnings?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`Watir::Wait#until` is not deprecated. The warnings are stating that there is a change to how the method should be called:

```
Watir::Wait.until(30) {browser.execute_script("return jQuery.active") == 0}
#=> "Instead of passing arguments into Wait#until method, use keywords"
```

To remove the warning, pass the timeout value, "30", using the `:timeout` keyword:

```
Watir::Wait.until(timeout: 30) {browser.execute_script("return jQuery.active") == 0}
```

Comment: Please consider accepting the question. It helps keep SO neat and tidy.